# Empty MySQL query result not working as expected?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, header

I am using the following script to check a code, so when the user enters the survey code they get the survey that is associated with that code. The part that fetches the survey is working as its supposed to, but I cant seem to get the error message to come up for some reason. If I enter a wrong code or no code all on the form this posts from, all I get is a blank page.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassword;
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

// Select mysql db
mysql_select_db("mydb", $con);

$questionaireID = $_POST['questionaireID'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM itsnb_questionaire WHERE questionaireID='$questionaireID'") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if (empty($row['questionaireID'])) {
        echo '<h2>Sorry I cant find a quiz with that code, please recheck your code.</h2>';
    } else {
        $url = $row['questionaireurl'];
        header('Location: '.$url.'');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This is because the first call of mysql_fetch_array returns FALSE, which means the content of the while loop is never executed (when the query returns an empty set). Have a look at functions like mysql_num_rows http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php that can tell you how many rows the return set contains

Comment: It looks like you did'nt close the parentheses in your $con statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will never get there, because if the resultset is empty, it'll skip the while loop.

Try this, instead, limiting to 1 record (which is what you expect) and using an `if...else` instead of your `while` (while is only required when multiple results are expected):

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM itsnb_questionaire 
        WHERE questionaireID = '{$questionaireID}'
        LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $url = $row['questionaireurl'];
    header('Location: '.$url.'');
} else {
    echo '<h2>Sorry I cant find a quiz with that code, please recheck your code.</h2>';
}
```

Comment: Was just waiting for the time limit to elapse :-)

Answer (score 1):

If number of returned rows is zero than you haven't found your result therefore you can display apropriate error message

try

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result)<1){
     //error
 }
```

Comment: Can you explain more regarding the code in your answer? Why should this code be tried?

Comment: If number of returned rows is zero than you haven't found your result therefore you can display apropriate error message